# Way to populate .csv with scraped data in Python with pandas that's closest to 'print'

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I managed to scrape multiple pages and I can print my results correctly with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.marketresearch.com/search/results.asp?qtype=2&datepub=3&publisher=Technavio&categoryid=0&sortby=r'

def scrape_it(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    NextUrl = soup.find_all(class_="standardLinkDkBlue")[-1]['href']
    stri = soup.find_all(class_="standardLinkDkBlue")[-1].string
    html_text = requests.get(NextUrl).text
    reports = soup.find_all('tr', class_='SearchTableRowAlt')
    for report in reports:
        title = report.find('a', class_='linkTitle').text
        price = report.find('div', class_='resultPrice').text
        date_author = report.find('div', class_='textGrey').text
        detail_link = report.a['href']

    print(f'''
    {title}
    {price}
    {date_author}
    {detail_link}
    ''')
```

Now, for getting this into .csv, I'm trying to create an array instead of printing so I replace the print(f''' ... ''') with:

```
final_res = [title, price, date_author, detail_link]
df = pd.DataFrame(final_res)
df.to_csv('results-tech.csv')
```

Well, it works for the first result (places the output in 4 rows of .csv), but the 'print' pulled data from all reports (over 250 of them) and all pages.

How can I do this to get correct and complete data written into my .csv?

Comment: Will you please show more of your code?

Comment: Voted to close, cause your question needs more details / clarity, please update so that everybody could reproduce the exact issue and does not have to make any assumptions. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, edited to show more code.

Answer (score 0):

#### What happens?

Actually you are not storing or returning any information and your indentation of printing is outside the loop.

#### How to fix?

Store the information from iteration in a list of dicts and return it to create a data frame from it:

```
data = []
    
for report in reports:
    data.append({
            'title' : report.find('a', class_='linkTitle').text,
            'price' : report.find('div', class_='resultPrice').text,
            'date_author' : report.find('div', class_='textGrey').text,
            'detail_link' : report.a['href']
    })

    return data
```

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.marketresearch.com/search/results.asp?qtype=2&datepub=3&publisher=Technavio&categoryid=0&sortby=r'

def scrape_it(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    NextUrl = soup.find_all(class_="standardLinkDkBlue")[-1]['href']
    stri = soup.find_all(class_="standardLinkDkBlue")[-1].string
    html_text = requests.get(NextUrl).text
    reports = soup.find_all('tr', class_='SearchTableRowAlt')
    
    data = []
    
    for report in reports:
        data.append({
            'title' : report.find('a', class_='linkTitle').text,
            'price' : report.find('div', class_='resultPrice').text,
            'date_author' : report.find('div', class_='textGrey').text,
            'detail_link' : report.a['href']
        })

    return data
    
pd.DataFrame(scrape_it(url))
```

#### Output

```
    title   price   date_author detail_link
0   Global Intermodal Freight Transportation Marke...   USD 2,500   9/15/2021 | published by: TechNavio https://www.marketresearch.com/Infiniti-Resear...
1   Global Baby Stroller Market 2021-2025   USD 2,500   9/16/2021 | published by: TechNavio https://www.marketresearch.com/Infiniti-Resear...
2   Global Fuel Cell Commercial Vehicle Market 202...   USD 2,500   9/8/2021 | published by: TechNavio  https://www.marketresearch.com/Infiniti-Resear...
3   Global Industrial Automation Services Market 2...   USD 2,500   9/7/2021 | published by: TechNavio  https://www.marketresearch.com/Infiniti-Resear...
4   Global Induction Hobs Market 2021-2025  USD 2,500   9/7/2021 | published by: TechNavio  https://www.marketresearch.com/Infiniti-Resear...
5   Global Probe Card Market 2021-2025  USD 2,500   9/3/2021 | published by: TechNavio  https://www.marketresearch.com/Infiniti-Resear...
6   Global Heat pump Market 2021-2025   USD 2,500   8/31/2021 | published by: TechNavio https://www.marketresearch.com/Infiniti-Resear...
7   Global Household Water Softener System Market ...   USD 2,500   8/30/2021 | published by: TechNavio https://www.marketresearch.com/Infiniti-Resear...
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much! The indentation was probably just mis-pasted, but worked in the code. But yeah - I guess that's the difference between printing and outputting to another file - print works as the code runs whereas outputting elsewhere requires a store of data. Thank so much for your help!